# C# Reusing timers vs Allocating new one

Tags: c#

Should I reuse timers or allocating new one on demand? Do many sleeping timers `timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite)` consumes resources?

P.S: I'm talking about `System.Threading.Timer` class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, in the current implementation of the .NET framework, timers that are changed to infinite timeout do not consume system ressources (except the memory used to store the instance itself), because they are actually deleted from the internal timer queue:

```
if (dueTime == Timeout.UnsignedInfinite)
{
    TimerQueue.Instance.DeleteTimer(this);
    success = true;
}
```

quoted from [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs,570)